# Cannot seem to center mdichild in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried as follows when clicking on a menu but the form still appears to be on the top left of the mdichild.I have also tried manual position but does not work.

Any suggestions?

```
     Form1 form= new Form1{MdiParent = this};
     form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
     form.Show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen ;
```

Comment: @user231465, this works for me (took your 3 lines of code and used `CenterScreen`).  `CenterParent` works if you call `ShowDialog`, but then `form` cannot be an mdi child.

Comment: Just found out why not working.Basically 1)lauch app 2)mdiParent is not maximized 3)maximizing the form does not center the mdichild.If I maximize the mdiParent before launching the child that works. I have added code in the resize event of mdiparent setting startposition of activechild to CenterScreen but that does not work

Comment: @user231456 for that you have to set form.Left and form.Top property.